# оборот "глядя на нас(,) как на рудиментарный придаток"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая? Или здесь *приравнивание, отождествление?*

> ...глядя на нас(,)  как на рудиментарный придаток, непригодный в новой системе...

Answer (score 3):

> ...глядя на нас как на рудиментарный придаток, непригодный в новой системе...

=

> глядя на нас как на утративших своё значение, как на ненужных в этой системе.

По мне, здесь явное приравнивание, отождествление, запятой нет.   Мы - это рудиментарный  придаток, судя по взгляду...

Comment: Людмила, а вы видели, как трактует отождествление "Справка" и Лопатин? У "грамотных" вообще нет этого слова, а у Лопатина отождествление - только **при сказуемом**. Да и по построению фразы как-то не верю я что, здесь может быть приравнивание иное, чем приравнивание взглядов. Но я никогда не слышал, чтобы на "рудиментарный придаток" смотрели как на что-то особенное.

Comment: Так ведь здесь рудиментарное=ненужное, а не особенное, а взгляд на нечто ненужное мы вполне представляем. Что сказуемое, что деепричастный оборот - разница небольшая, это действия, только одно основное, другое добавочное.

Answer (score 1):

**Оборот не обособляется:** ....глядя на нас как на рудиментарный придаток, непригодный в новой системе...

**Правило:** Оборот с союзом КАК со значением тождества не обособляется, если **тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым в основном сообщении**. В этом случае оборот имеет значение « в качестве, считая, рассматривая".

**Значение  «считая»:**       Все относились к нему как к чудаку.

**Значение  «рассматривая»:** Смотрите на меня как на пациента.

**Значение  «в качестве»:**  Я говорю как литератор. Любое внимание к своему творчеству он воспринимал как похвалу.

Answer (score -1):

> Или здесь приравнивание, отождествление?
>   А почему "или"?

Alenka, потому и по-разному, что тут объективно можно трактовать и так и эдак. Грамматической ошибки не будет и с запятой, и баз неё. А вот что касается смысловой...

Давайте так. Здесь есть только две теоретически мыслимых мотивации для выбора пунктуации. Либо это сравнительный оборот, либо это обстоятельство образа действия.

http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183

Остальные случаи явно "не наши". Иногда по-другому эти пункты называют, и число из меняется, но здесь понятнее. Главное, что нет слов "приравнивание", (которые только путают в отрыве от смыслового "обстоятельство образа действия).

Так вот сами по судите, что надежнее соответствует мысли автора, сравнение чего-то там с придатком - или же сравнение чьего-то взгляда с таким, каким смотрят на придаток?!

По мне так первое. Я могу понять, как кого-то сравнивают с придатком, но я затрудняюсь объяснить, какой бывает взгляд у смотрящего на "рудиментарный придаток". Поэтому, склонен трактовать это как сравнение, для обстоятельства образа действия тут явно недостаточная мотивация.

Вывод. Если согласный с моим пониманием фразы, пишите с запятой.
***...глядя на нас, как на рудиментарный придаток, непригодный в новой системе...***

(+)

"Во избежание" добавлю сюда и мнение Лопатина.

> § 90. Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) как, словно,
>   будто, точно, как будто, что не выделяются запятыми в следующих
>   случаях:
>
> а) при сказуемом, требующем конкретизации (оборот имеет значение
>   отождествления или приравнивания): *Вот почему она смотрела на землю
>   как на юдоль скорби (Нов.-Пр.);...*

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=262

Надо сказать, что это пример несколько спорен (в отличие от безусловных последующих у Лопатина), отсутствие запятой неочевидно.

Но в любом случае здесь-то речь идет о сказуемом!!! И только поэтому Лопатин говорит об отождествлении. Распространение же этого положения на деепричастие весьма сомнительно.